# Php-yii2- hybridauth authentication failed on cancel

Tags: php, facebook, yii2, hybridauth

Hi I am trying to login with `hybridauth` Its working fine but if user click on cancel its showing error. How i can redirect user to specific  page on my site on clicking cancel button.

```
Authentication failed! The user denied your request.
```

here how I am calling hybridauth

```
 $auth = new \Hybrid_Auth(Yii::$app->params['hybridConfig']);
        $adapter = $auth->authenticate($provider);
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
        $accessToken = $adapter->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Did you have an actual question?

Comment: Yes what you need to understand ..